# Inner text doesn't change

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning JavaScript and I thought I would make a Tic-Tac-Toe game to practice.

I have a function named: `displayMessage()` that changes the text inside a `<p>` tag.

```
function displayMessage(message) {
turn_p.innerHTML = message}
```

Whenever it changes turns, I call this function and it works as expected.

```
function setNextPlayerTurn(currentPlayer) {
currentPlayer === "X" ? player = "O" : player = "X"
displayMessage(`${player}'s turn!`)}
```

But when I call it when the game ends to show the winner, it doesn't work.

```
function endGame() {
cells.forEach((cell) => {
    cell.removeEventListener('click', turnClick, false);
})
displayMessage(`${player} player Won!`)}
```

The `endGame()` function is called by another function named: `checkWin()`.If `checkWin()` is true it calls `endGame()`.

```
function checkWin() {
if (checkFirstRow() ||
    checkSecondRow() ||
    checkThirdtRow() ||
    checkFirstColumn() ||
    checkSecondColumn() ||
    checkThirdColumn() ||
    checkMainDiagonal() ||
    checkSecondaryDiagonal() == true) {
    endGame()
}}
```

What can I do to fix this problem?

Full code: https://jsfiddle.net/yrgs16av/

Comment: What exactly does "it doesn't work" mean? Does *anything* happen? Is an error reported? What have you done to investigate the problem?

Comment: The text on the < p> tag doesn't change. I've tried not calling de fucntion and simply putting: turn_p.innerHTML =`${player} player Wins!` and It didn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried adding `console.log()` calls to verify that `endGame()` is even being called?

Comment: Yes, I tried. I'ts being called.

Comment: what exactly *is* happening? I can think of a few possible issues, but would need to see more code to know what the issue could be.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I've added the full functions code.

Comment: @BrunoCauan that wasn't really what I was after. I really want to see the *full* code (provided it's not hundreds of lines wrong), but what I'm particularly interested in is 1) for you to describe what text actually gets put into that `<p>` tag when the game ends, 2) where the `player` variable is declared/defined

Comment: Hi @RobinZigmond I've added the full code. The checkRows and checkCollums functions I will refactor later I just wanted to see if it worked.

Comment: Please create a [MCVE], including HTML and relevant CSS

Comment: OK, I just checked the JSFiddle and played around. Your code is actually working (insert a `debugger` statement at the end of the `endGame` function to see the desired "winner" message. The problem is that you're instantly going on to the next turn regardless - which includes setting the message to the next player's turn.

Comment: All relevant code should be included *in the question itself* .  Make it as easy as possible for us to help you by keeping your code on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

just as @Robin Zigmond said the problem was that it'was instantly going on to the next turn regardless - which includes setting the message to the next player's turn.

I made a few changes and It worked.

```
    function turn(squareId) {
        //code...
        checkWinAndDraw();
        if (gameEnded != true) {
            setNextPlayerTurn(player);
        }
}

        function checkWinAndDraw() {
        if (//condition)
        } else {
            checkDraw();
        }}

        function checkDraw() {
        if (board.every(square => square == 'X' || square == 'O')) {
            displayMessage(`It's a Draw!`);
            gameEnded = true;
        }
    }

    function endGame() {
        //code...
        displayMessage(`${player} player Won!`)
        gameEnded = true;
    }
```